# How to plot the shape of a 2D wavelet?

Tags: wavelet, visualization, pywavelets

I often see images like this:

[image]

where on the left it depicts 2D wavelets and on the right curvelets for different scales and locations.

How can I visualize different 2D wavelets/curvelets in such a way using Matlab or Python (e.g. using pywavelets)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Transform to time domain
2. Center
3. Plot real & imag separately, or use complex colormap, or take modulus

Results below.

[image]
[image]

#### Minimal code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import ifft, ifftshift
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 2048
w = np.linspace(0, 1, N, 0)
psi_x = ifftshift(ifft(np.exp(-(w - .0125 )**2 * 2**19)))
psi_y = ifftshift(ifft(np.exp(-(w - .00625)**2 * 2**20)))
Psi = psi_x * psi_y[:, None]
plt.imshow(Psi.real, cmap='bwr')
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks! Could you maybe provide a minimal example, e.g. for plotting \Psi_{2,3,+1}? I was able to install the package, but can't import for example the "visuals" module.

Comment: @stish Forgot to provide install; try `pip install git+https://github.com/kymatio/kymatio.git@refs/pull/674/head`

Comment: Thanks! Was able to import "filterbank_jtfs", but is "kymatio.scattering1d.TimeFrequencyScattering1D" still correct?

Comment: @stish Right, it's the most recent and final version. If it's still not working I'd try to clone the repository with and switch to branch `pr/674`

Comment: Sorry i cloned the repo but cant find branch pr/674 there.

Comment: @stish Alternatively `fix-672`, or clone branch [directly](https://github.com/lostanlen/kymatio/tree/fix-672)

Comment: @stish Added minimal code.